# Enum doesnt work in where Clause in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums

```
enum gender: [:Male, :Female]
```

When I query

```
User.where(:gender => "Female", :created_at => 0.days.ago.beginning_of_day..Time.current
```

It not working according to query.It still pointing Male.How I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Set enum as:

```
enum gender: [:male, :female]
```

And query like below:

```
User.female.where(created_at: 0.days.ago.beginning_of_day..Time.current)
```

Also I believe you can use settings below for better looking and understanding:

in app/models/user.rb, set scope for time duration:

```
scope :today, -> { where(created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_day..Time.now) }
```

And query like this:

```
User.female.today
```

Comment: Hi @haseeb how do you think this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do like this:

```
User.where(gender: User.genders[:Female], 
           created_at: 0.days.ago.beginning_of_day..Time.current)
```